# Set different stylesheet for div and all child-nodes?

Tags: css, stylesheet, encapsulation

I'm wondering if there is a possibility to make a div ignore all css rules in the document and instead using a different stylesheet for itself and all of its child nodes.

A little example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            div{color:red}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>This is red text</div>
        <div stylesheet="/path/to/my/stylesheet.css">
            This is text in a color defined in the other stylesheet
            <div>This is also not red</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I want to define a stylesheet directly onto a div, and not globally. Is there a way to do something like that?

What I want to achieve is more encapsulation of my code. I know there also possibilities like pseudo-namespacing, but that's ugly as hell and still does not guarantee that there are no conflicts...

**Update**

In the meantime, I've found the "scoped" attribute of style elements, which does a very similar thing to what I requested. But it's supported by almost no browser.

Are there better solutions?

Comment: why do you make it so complicated? You only need to use a normal stylesheet and make different classes for your divs. You can then also reach the child-elements of this classes. No need to load different stylesheets for every div.

Comment: @Sven Bieder I know that. But in really big projects, it happens very fast, that class names clash, especially when using some thirdparty libraries. With a feature like i requested it, you could, prevent conflicts with thirdparty stylesheets. Have you, for example, ever tried to add the bootstrap css files to an existing project? It affects your whole page. If you want only a single element to use the bootstrap style, you're pretty much out of luck.

Comment: No, I don't use pre-made CSS frameworks. I develop very custom front end solution for web apps, so I know exactly what big projects mean. Using the bootstrap like it is will be at every time a bad idea. You must figure out what features you need and then tweek the base to it and get rid of the rest. But the idea of loading endless stylesheet files will give you a big performance hit. While developing I also use several stylesheets. But before it goes to production I concatenate them to one or two files (also third-party styles get concatenated). Careful planning of naming is the key.

Comment: @Andy 1) it was just an example and 2) I wouldn't include bootstrap for only one element, but when there is a very big part of the page that needs bootstrap, what then? ;)

Comment: I have a similar problem myself now, I am using GWT, and my app loads into a webpage and replaces that webpage entirely once it is loaded, however, because the original webpage has multiple CSS files associated with it, and not everything in my GWT app has a class or ID associated with it. I am struggling to figure out which bits to remove and/or which bits to re-classify, its a LOT of work!! it would be great if I could just do as the above suggests!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to do this without a `<style scoped>` attribute. And, as you said, that is horribly unsupported. [This is a jQuery plugin for scoped styles](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin) on GitHub, and it pushes support for a lot more browsers. You'd also be able to `@import other-stylesheet.css` in your scoped style definition with this jQuery plugin.

All things considered though, you might actually be better off using multiple classes on one element. Give a div a couple of classes, and you can organize your projects fairly decently. Something like `<div class="parent child grandchildren-1">` would only be selected by this css:

```
.parent.child.grandchildren-1 { color:red; }
```

Comment: I really wonder what they have thought when they "designed" the scoped style element, because it's crap. They'd better have added a "style-src" attribute, or a "namespace" attribute to all elements, but defining scoped css inline does not make sense to me. If it would not be possible to @import, the whole thing would be completely useless. But since it is possible, it's usable, but ugly, since I need to place a style element into my div and there's no way to apply the scoped style to just one element and not to all on the same level...

Comment: CSS *does* have namespaces, but we normally call them *classes* or *ids*: `.foo {  } .foo p {  }`

Comment: @cimmanon that's not namespacing. There can be child nodes in your "foo"-elements, that don't belong to you or your namespace. But .foo{} would still match such elements. Namespacing as I imagine it would be that an element would inherit its namespace from its parent, until another namespace is specified. classes can't be inherited, which would mean, that you would have to include the the whole "class-path" to your element in your css rule, and not just your namespace+class - or you will maybe include some false-positives, as I already mentioned.